# row_number() FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, select

I have an sql-statement, which should select all content of a table ordered by the row number. So i used the row_number function.

But I get everytime the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

or this error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

My statement looks like this:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY table.column1) AS row, table.* 
FROM table 
WHERE column2= ("Any String") 
ORDER BY row;
```

I hope you can help me with this code.

Comment: I'm guessing `table` isn't the real table name - but is `row` the column name you're attempting to use? Because it's a [Reserved name](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm) in Oracle.

Comment: @sshekhar - the final result order is *not* guaranteed without specifying an `ORDER BY` on it. The server may have been able to applying row numbers via means other than sorting, and without the final `ORDER BY`, is under no obligation to return the rows in any particular order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to use the name `row` for that result column, you'll have issues since it's a [Reserved Word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm) in Oracle. Either pick a different name for the column, or surround it with `""` quotes (a [quoted identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements9a.htm):

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY table.column1) AS "row", table.* 
FROM table 
WHERE column2= ("Any String") 
ORDER BY "row";
```

(I'd generally opt for picking a different name though)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but maybe you have to select the columns for working with their, try syh like this:

```
SELECT name_column1, name_column2, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER( ORDER BY name_column1) AS THE_NAME_THAT_YOU_WANT
FROM NAME_OF_TABLE
WHERE name_column2 ="any_string";
```

take a look to the origin of error:

ORA-00923 originates from the necessity for the keyword FROM to follow the final selected item in a SELECT statement, or privileges in a REVOKE statement.  When ORA-00923 is thrown, it is because a SELECT or REVOKE statement has one of the following problematic syntaxes in the keyword FROM:

1. missing
2. misspelled
3. misplaced

There are many areas of interest when resolving ORA-00923:

You should appropriately correct the syntax, inserting the keyword FROM where necessary.
    Keep in mind that the SELECT list itself could be in error, which could also cause ORA-00923 to appear.
    Quotation marks should also be evaluated when correcting ORA-00923, as they should enclose the alias (if used within the alias).
    Also, find out if you used a reserve word as an alias.

Comment: no it's the same error again. from keyword not where expected.

Answer (score 0):

Which DBMS is that?
Why don't you drop the parentheses and use like this:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY table.column1) AS row, table.* 
FROM table 
WHERE column2 = 'Any String' 
ORDER BY row;
```

Comment: because 'any string is a variable.